# ¿Cómo puedo separar diferentes fechas para sumarlas, pero son de una misma persona?

Tags: php, mysql

Mi sistema trata de los registros de entrada y salida de la mañana y la tarde de los empleados.

La tabla en donde se está registrando las entradas y salidas se rellena automáticamente al importar un excel, las columnas de mi tabla son el `id`, `num_checador`,  tiempo(en donde va la fecha y el día de registro), y el `estado` que ve si es entrada y salida, se supone que **por día deben de ser 4 registros, 2 entradas y 2 salidas.**

Mi pregunta es:

**Como puedo separar la entrada y salida del día de la mañana de una sola persona en un solo arreglo para sumarlas y sacar el tiempo total?** E igual otro arreglo con la entrada y salida de la tarde pero del mismo día y de la misma persona. En este ejemplo necesitaría separar la información del mismo empleado con el numero de checador #8 del día 21/07/2.

Aclaro que estoy programando en php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Vos queres hacer esto en php o mysql?? la respuesta es muy pero muy diferente...

Comment: Quiero hacerlo en php, ya que mi base de datos está en mysql pero quiero poner una tabla en la pagina donde me muestre las horas y la suma de ellas, como una tabla en una hoja de cálculo.

Comment: Mi recomendación es que todo lo que hagas en el servidor de bases de datos evita el trasiego de los datos necesarios para realizar los cálculos. Mejor que del MySQL al Apache viaje únicamente el resultado, sobre todo si están en máquinas distintas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar con algo así:

```
SELECT *,
  TIMEDIFF(salida_mañana,entrada_mañana) mañana,
  TIMEDIFF(salida_tarde,entrada_tarde) tarde,
  (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(salida_mañana,entrada_mañana))+
  TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(salida_tarde,entrada_tarde)))/60/60 total_horas
  FROM (
    SELECT num_checador,DATE(tiempo) dia,
      MIN(tiempo) entrada_mañana,MAX(tiempo) entrada_tarde
      FROM personal
      WHERE estado='Entrada'
      GROUP BY 1,2  
  ) c1 JOIN (
    SELECT num_checador,DATE(tiempo) dia,
      MIN(tiempo) salida_mañana,MAX(tiempo) salida_tarde
      FROM personal
      WHERE estado='Salida'
      GROUP BY 1,2  
  ) c2 USING(num_checador,dia);
```

Partiendo de este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE personal(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  num_checador int,
  tiempo datetime,
  estado varchar(15)
  );
INSERT INTO personal (num_checador, tiempo, estado) VALUES
  (8,'2022-07-21  9:06:32','Entrada'),
  (8,'2022-07-21 13:32:28','Salida'),
  (8,'2022-07-21 15:34:39','Entrada'),
  (8,'2022-07-21 19:00:22','Salida');
```

Obtendrás:

```
+--------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| num_checador | dia        | entrada_mañana      | entrada_tarde       | salida_mañana       | salida_tarde        | mañana   | tarde    | total_horas |
+--------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
|            8 | 2022-07-21 | 2022-07-21 09:06:32 | 2022-07-21 15:34:39 | 2022-07-21 13:32:28 | 2022-07-21 19:00:22 | 04:25:56 | 03:25:43 |  7.86083333 |
+--------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Espero que fuera lo que buscabas. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para ampliar la respuesta en la dirección en la que necesites aclaraciones.

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba!!! Muchísimas gracias, solamente que el tipo de dato en mi base de datos en la columna tiempo la tengo como varchar, la tengo que cambiar para poder usar las funciones TIMEDIFF, o TIME_TO_SEC

Comment: `ALTER TABLE personal MODIFY tiempo DATETIME;`